# What version of AEM/CQ5 page will be seen when a page is already in a separate workflow?

Tags: workflow, branch, aem

If you take a page and put it in a workflow, then if someone wants to modify that page – in an emergency situation and essentially start another workflow on it –

1. Is that possible to send that page through another workflow?
2. If you don’t want to send the same page through a workflow, but just want to edit it, can you?

Apparently If one person is editing a CQ page and same page is edited by someone else at the same time, at production level, how the CQ / developer handles the situation?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not possible to subject a page to more than one workflow at once, none of the interfaces allow this to happen.
2. The pages can be edited even when they are subject to a workflow. In emergency situations where in it is not possible to complete the workflow , users with required privileges can terminate the workflow from the **instances** tab of the workflow console (/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html). Pages can be usually activated even if they are subject to workflows.
3. The repository is accessed via repository session. Based on the credentials provided the user gets a repository session. Any changes made via that session is only visible to the other users when the session is saved. Since different sessions are used , multiple users can edit the same page simultaneously. The data in dialogs are loaded via asynchronous GET requests when *EDIT* is clicked and not on page load , so it is very unlikely that the user will be editing old data. They can still overwrite some other user's changes. Developers do not have to handle these situations unless there is some special requirement. If a user wants to stop other users from editing a page , they can use the [**lock**](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/wcm/page_publish.html#Locking%20Pages) functionality that comes out of the box. A locked page can be unlocked only by the user who locked it or an administrator. A [page](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#lock()) or [node](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#lock(boolean,%20boolean)) can be programmatically locked via the JCR API.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sharath, Is it possible to use launches in this situation. Also How do I use a launch if I wanted to created a launches of launched version. For example - I have a launch version A then how do I created a launch B version which I need to create not from the live or production copy but from the launch version itself?

Comment: why do you want such a set up ? Launches are used to add content in addition to already published content over time before publishing , while keeping it in sync with changes to published page. Why opt for this associative way of moving changes from published page to Launch A and from Launch A to Launch B ? why not make these changes in Launch A directly ?

Comment: Hi @Sharath,I have a requirement say I have 2 projects inline to go for production. Project 1 will go live in 2 months and project 2 in another 2 months after  the release of Project 1. Here there is a dependency of project 2 in project 1. so when I wanted to test my project 2 before putting it on production, I need some synced environment where I already have project 1 deployed same as production. I am looking for a solution where by using the launches and branches, I can resolve the issue. Please suggest if you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to check if project 2's code doesn't break any thing in project 1 right ? Why not take package of content of production and test in another environment like stage

Comment: Basically I want automatic synchronization between production branch and launches here. There will be production CRs and Projects; which will be individual launches from prod and get auto-synced. In our case since all the projects are from prod, synchronization between projects that haven't gone live is not possible using simple approach. So here are my concerns :  1. Is there a way to synchronize between the launches.   2. Once project 1 goes live, is there a way to  switch synchronization between prod and project 2 launch?